# Extracting ListBox to separate file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

So, i have quite complex ListBox, with own style and composite item templates (in every item, there are image and text, both with click events, which rises corresponding commands in global viewmodel). What would be the easiest way to re-use that ListBox?

Should i extract style only, or move it out as UserControl, or should i make new component? Everything is static (commands, markup) exept content (should be able to use different items lists).

In the perfect case, is should be (pseudocode):

Page 1 xaml

```
<MyListBox Content={Binding Page1List}>
```

Page 1 vm

```
ObservableCollection<Items> Page1List;
```

and so on for other pages.

EDIT: i found [this](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-access-a-control-placed-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-in-wp7) article - that makes sence, but i think there should be easier way for that.

Comment: The purpose defines your answer. Listbox itself is very generic. You have to make more specific to your application and needs. Usercontrol looks good when you want such type of listbox in all other pages. Creating component seems ugly to me.

Comment: @max Yep, i have one style/template of listbox, which i need to show on different pages with different context. I'll look deeper to UC, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14340/Creating-a-look-less-custom-control-in-WPF

I believe the solution you are looking for is a look-less control.

Comment: Yes, but article is only about style changes. The problem is that i have style, which defines, say, "2 buttons in each listboxitem". So if i define commands inside of style, i cant get access to listboxitem itself.